There is no polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $\{ 0, 1 \}$, such that $f(x) - 8$ is a multiple of $x^3 + x^2 - 2$.
When working on this problem, to show that Julio's solution has a gap, that led to the following:

There is no polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $\{ 0, 1 \}$, such that $f(x) - 8$ is a multiple of $x^3 + x^2 - 2$.

I was able to prove that in the postamble in my solution (tedious solution, reproduced below). I would like to ask:

Is there another proof?

I looked at the remainders of $x^n$ mod $x^3 + x^2  - 2$, but didn't find a noticable pattern.
The remainders of $x^n$ mod $x^2 + 2x + 2$ has a pattern because $(x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2 ) = x^4 + 4$, but I couldn't exploit it to get a solution.
- There is a unique $f(x) - 8$ that is a multiple of $ x^2 + 2x + 2$, and it's not a multiple of $x^3 + x^2 - 2$, so maybe that could be a valid approach. That's essentially what my solution showed.
Note: This is not a solution-verification post, though if there are issues please let me know.


Can we show this for other any other $f(x) - n$?

In particular, for $n\leq 7$, I can find such a polynomial.
$n= 9$ doesn't work for the same reason (Add $x^0 $ to $f(x)$.)
My solution isn't easily generalizable. 1/ It tedious calculates the coefficients, so we have to restart each time. 2/ Even though we can hunt down the $a_i$ coefficients, I ended up having to make a unique observation. Had I continued the process, I would get "We have to use 0" for $i \geq 9$, and explained it via some pattern.   3/ Because I use the observation about $x^2 + 2x + 2$, it might be possible that this approach can't deal with all possible cases. (Note that looking at $ x - 1$ in the denominator is necessary for the original problem's $f(1) = n$, but I've not needed this condition. In that sense, I think this approach should still work.)
Having said that, I can show that $n = 10, 11, 12, 13$ do not work either.

Testing $n = 10$ (and 11), my approach works with $f(x) = x^2 + x^3 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + \sum x^{b_i} $ and $ \frac{ x^2 + x^3 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8  - 10 } { x^2 + 2x + 2 } = x^6 - x^5 + x^5 - 2x%2 + 5x - 5$.
Testing $ n = 12$ (and 13), my approach works with $f(x) = x^4 + x^8 + \sum x^{b_i} $ and $ \frac{ x^8 + x^4 - 12 }{x^2 + 2x + 2 } = x^6 - 2x^5 + 2x^4 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6$.






My solution: Suppose $ f_j(x) - 8  = ( x^3 + x^2 - 2) (\sum a_i x^i)$, then let's find the coefficients $a_i$

Looking at the $x^0$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 8 = -2(a_0)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_ 0 = 4$
Looking at the $x^1$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - 4(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 0 = -2(a_1)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_1 = 0$.
Looking at the $x^2$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - 4(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_2)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_2 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^3$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_3)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_3 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^4$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 2 = -2(a_4)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_4 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^5$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 4 = -2(a_5)$, hence we have to use 0, and $a_5 = 2$.
Looking at the $x^6$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_6)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_6 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^7$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5 + x^6)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_7)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_7 = 1$.
Looking at the $x^8$ coefficient of $f_j(x) - 8 - (4+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5 + x^6+x^7)(x^3 + x^2 - 2)$, since $ \{ 0 \text{ or } 1 \} - 3 = -2(a_8)$, hence we have to use 1, and $a_8 = 1$.
At this point, we have $ f(x) = x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + \sum x^{b_i} $ (higher order terms).

Since $x^3 + x^2 - 2 = ( x -1 ) (x^2 + 2x + 2)$, hence $ \frac{ f(x) - 8 } { x^2 + 2x + 2 } $ is also a polynomial.
Notice that $\frac{x^8 + x^7  + x^6 - 8 }{ x^2 + 2x + 2} = x^6 - x^5 + x^4  - 2x^2 + 4x - 4 $, so $ \frac{ \sum x^{b_i} } { x^2 + 2x + 2} $ is a polynomial.
So the smallest exponent with non-zero coefficient (which is 1) must be even, thus we have a contradiction. This means that there are no larger terms.
However, $ \frac{ x^8 + x^7 + x^6 - 8 } { x^3 + x^2 - 2} = x^5 + x^3 + x^2 - x + 3 + \frac{ -x^2 - 2x - 2 } { x^3 + x^2 - 2 } $ is not a polynomial.


Note that we cannot stick to using $x^3 + x^2 - 2$ in the denominator. (Or at least, I cannot get a contradiction that way.)


A very simple question, by "multiple of $f(x)$" do you mean $\lambda f(x)$ with $\lambda$ constant or $g(x)f(x)$?

@Piquito $g(x) f(x)$  (To me, that's the standard definition / interpretation). Also, if you read the rest of the post, that should be obvious.

Thanks you. My question was before reading your solution (I hope now appears your name which was deleted in my question).

$f(1)=8\implies \sum_{k=1}^{8}(-1+i)^{n_k}=8$ ,then inspect the pattern in sequence $(-1+i)^n$, I guess this can help.

@QuýNhân I've tried essentially that by looking at the remainders of $x^n$ mod $x^2 + 2x + 2$, but was unable to push through. Can you elaborate on what else to do? $\quad$ Note that we can find a 0-1 polynomial such that $f(x) - 8$ is a multiple of $x^2 + 2x + 2$ (so that throws a slight wrinkle into your plan). The saving grace is that this polynomial is unique, and is not a multiple of $ x^3 + x^2 - 2$, hence we are done.

Let $f(x)-N=g(x)(x^3+x^2-2)=g(x)(x-1)(x-(-1+i))(x-(-1-i))$, $g(x)$ is any polynomial (no constraint on $g(x)$), we have: $$([x^{k}]f(x)\in\{0,1\})\wedge(f(1)=N)\implies f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}x^{n_{k}}\implies f(-1+i)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}(-1+i)^{n_{k}}=N$$
$A=\{n_{k}|1\leq k\leq 8\}$ is some set of distinct non-negative integers
Lemma 1: $R_{n}=\textrm{Re}((-1+i)^n)=16^{n/8}a_{n\%8}$ and $I_{n}=\textrm{Im}((-1+i)^{n})=16^{n/8}b_{n\%8}$
(Note: Pay attention. Sometimes I use $X_{n}$ as sequence, sometimes as numbers.)
$\{a_{k}\}_{k=0}^{7}=(1,-1,0,2,-4,4,0,-8)\ ;\ \{b_{k}\}_{k=0}^{7}=(0,1,-2,2,0,-4,8,-8)$
The operator I used $\cdot/\cdot$ means integer division, $\cdot\%\cdot$ means mod.
Now, the objective is to prove whether the for following is true for $N$:
$$\mathbb{B}(N)=\exists A:\begin{cases}\sum_{n\in A}R_{n}=N \\\sum_{n\in A}I_{n}=0 \end{cases}\tag{1}$$  By observation, it's easy to deduce that sequences $\{|R_{n}|\}_{0\leq n}$ and $\{|I_{n}|\}_{0\leq n}$ have non-decreasing non-zero subsequences and they (the unsigned sequences) cover all powers of $2$ and each power of $2$ never appear more than twice in each sequence ($\{R_{n}\}_{0\leq n},\{I_{n}\}_{0\leq n}$), if they appear twice, they have opposite signs (*). This leads to:
Lemma 2: ($X_{n}\in\{R_{n},I_{n}\}$), $\forall B:\ |\sum_{n\in B}X_{n}|\leq 2\underset{n\in B}{\max}(|X_{n}|)-1$, we know $\exists m:\ |X_{m}|=2\underset{n\in B}{\max}(|X_{n}|)$ (since $X_n$ covers all power of $2$). Combining two arguments:
$$1 \leq |X_{m}|-|\sum_{n\in B}X_{n}|\leq|X_{m}+\sum_{n\in B}X_{n}|=|\sum_{n\in B\cup\{m\}}X_{n}| \tag{2}$$
As consequence of (*) ,we can always uniquely partition any given set $B$ (assembling $A$) as $B_{o}$ and its complement $B_{o}^{c}$ where $\{X_{n}|n\in B_{o}\}$ (note that from now on, this notation does not mean a pure set, they can contain more than one $0$) contains only unique-absolute non-zero values and $\{X_{n}|n\in B_{o}^{c}\}$ contains $0s$ and coupled-values of same magnitude but different signs. By Lemma 2 (or $(2)$):
$$(\sum_{n\in B_{o}}X_{n}\not =0) \wedge (\sum_{n\in B_{o}^{c}}X_{n}=0)\tag{3}$$
Back to problem $(1)$. $\sum_{n\in A}I_{n}=0$ implies $A_{i}$ is empty (partitioned like $B$ to $B_{o}$) so we know $\{I_{n}|n\in A\}$ only contains zeros and couples of opposite-signed numbers. Thus:
$$\begin{Bmatrix}a_{k}\\b_{k}\end{Bmatrix}_{k=0}^{k=7}:\begin{pmatrix}\ &1 &X &0 &2 &-4\ &X &0 &-8\\&0 &X &-2 &2 &0 &X &8 &-8\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$
I deleted elements (replaced by $X$) that being singular on the second row and their companions on the first row. Let's have a look at non-zero elements of the "deleted" $R_n$:$K_{n}=(1,2,-4,-8,16,32,-64,-128,256,\ldots)$
Now we going to prove for every $m$ ,there exists a unique set $Y$ such that: $\sum_{k\in Y}K_{k}=2^{m}$
Lemma 3: $\forall C:|\sum_{n\in C}K_{n}|<2\underset{n\in C}{\max}(|K_{n}|)$. This means adding "higher" elements only make us move away from the initial value, while adding "lower" elements never bring us back to the initial value (well, this statement can be made rigorous but I'll skip it for now).
Consequently the existence of such $Y$ is unique, and we have a rule to find $Y$: $\exists k: K_{k}=2^{m}\implies Y=\{m\}$, else $Y=\{m,m+1,m+2\}$.
And we conclude that if $\exists Y:\sum_{n\in Y}K_{n}=n_{o}$ (some integer $n_{o}$), then $Y$ must be unique to $n_{o}$ since binary representation is unique and binary elements' constructions are unique. (1i)
I think those numbers without representation are those with binary representation having more than one of the elements in each triple belonging to $(\{2^2,2^3,2^4\},\{2^6,2^7,2^8\},\ldots)$. For example: $12,25,13\ldots$. But having binary representation is only a necessary condition. Now we turn back to the part containing $(3)$.
To make $(1)$ true with the fact $(3)$, we need to partition $A$ into $A_{r}$ and $A_{r}^{c}$, where $\sum_{n\in A_{r}}R_{n}=N$. By (1i), we know that $A_{r}$ is unique, then we determine what should be (or is it possible) $A_{r}^{c}$ so that $\sum_{n\in A}I_{n}=0$.
About those lemmas, they are "pretty straight forward", so I will skip them for now.
With the demonstrated technique, here is a collection of results:
$$ 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
N& \mathbb{B}(N)& f(x)&\\ \hline
1&  1&  1&\\ \hline
2&  1&  x^3+x^2&\\ \hline
3&  1&  x^3+x^2+x^0\\ \hline
4&  1&  x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4\\ \hline
5&  1&  x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^0\\ \hline
6&  1&  x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2 \\ \hline
7&  1&  x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+x^0\\ \hline
8&  0&  \textrm{DNE}&\\ \hline
9&  0&  \textrm{DNE}&\\ \hline
10&  0&  \textrm{DNE}&\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
The list goes on, I conjecture that $\mathbb{B}(N)=0,\ \forall N\geq 8$. The reason for this is as $N$ gets larger, we have to use more periodic cells (like $(4)$) and it becomes impossible to align $A_{r}$ and $A$ so that they both satisfy $(3)$.
Last comment. If you think my answer is hard to understand, you are right, I don't fully understand these things either, that's why it's difficult for me to write down these ideas. My answer may be not complete because I skipped quite a lot of details, I think I will improve this later.

Since $x^3+x^2-2=(x-1)(x-z)(x-\overline{z})$ where $z=-1+i$, if
$f(x)-8=(x^3+x^2-2)g(x)$ then  $f(1)=f(z)=8$.
Keeping into account the required form for $f(x)$ and $f(1)=8$, necessarily $f(x)$ is a sum of eight powers $x^{n_k}$ so
$$ f(x)=x^{n_1}+x^{n_2}+x^{n_3}+x^{n_4}+x^{n_5}+x^{n_6}+x^{n_7}+x^{n_8}$$ where we take the exponents arbitrary distinct and in increasing order.
It remains to prove that with such a necessary $f(x)$, it is not possible to have $f(z)=8$.
We have the table $$(1)\begin{cases}z=-1+i\\z^2=-2i\\z^3=2(1-i)\\z^4=-4\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}z^{4n+1}=(-4)^nz\\z^{4n+2}=(-4)^nz^2\\z^{4n+3}=(-4)^nz^3\\z^{4n}=(-4)^n\end{cases}$$ We need  $$f(z)=z^{n_1}+z^{n_2}+z^{n_3}+z^{n_4}+z^{n_5}+z^{n_6}+z^{n_7}+z^{n_8}=8$$
The exponents $n_k$, in increasing order, can be changed as needed to achieve $f(z)=8$ if this were possible.
Noting as usual $f(z)=A+iB$, we have $f(z)=A+iB=8\iff A=8\wedge B=0\implies n_1\gt1$ because $A$ should be even.
From $(1)$ we get $$(2)\begin{cases}z=-1+i\\z^2=-2i\\z^3=2(1-i)\\z^4=-4\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}z^{4n+1}=(-4)^nz\\z^{4n+2}=(-4)^nz^2\\z^{4n+3}=(-4)^nz^3\\z^{4n}=(-4)^n\end{cases}\implies$$ We need  $$f(z)=z^{n_1}+z^{n_2}+z^{n_3}+z^{n_4}+z^{n_5}+z^{n_6}+z^{n_7}+z^{n_8}=8$$
Recall that $n_1\ge2 $ and $z=-1+i$.
Noting $z^{n_k}=A_k+iB_k$ we have
$$f(z)=8\iff A=\sum_{k=1}^{k=8}A_k=8\space\wedge\space B=\sum_{k=1}^{k=8}B_k=0$$
This yields the following table:
$$(3)\begin{cases}z^{4n+1}=(-4)^n(-1+i)\iff (A_{4n+1},B_{4n+1})=(-(-4)^n,(-4)^n)\text { (only changed signs.) }  \\\\z^{4n+2}=(-4)^n(-2i) \hspace 0.5cm    \iff (A_{4n+2}, B_{4n+2})=(0,-2(-4)^n)\\\\z^{4n+3}=(-4)^n(2+2i)\iff (A_{4n+3},B_{4n+3})=(2(-4)^n,2(-4)^n)\text{ (both are equal!) }\\\\ z^{4n}\hspace0.3cm=(-4)^n\hspace1.5cm\space\space\iff (A_{4n}, B_{4n})\hspace0.6cm=((-4)^n,0)\end{cases}$$
$$\\$$
According with table $(3)$ the most evident way to have $B=0$ is to take each exponent $n_k\equiv0\pmod4$ with $1\le k\le 8$ the most lower set of fitting exponents giving the fonction $$f(x)=x^4+x^8+x^{12}+x^{16}+x^{20}+x^{24}+x^{28}+x^{32}$$ for which certainly $B=0$ but $A$ is quite greater than $8$ (in fact $A=52 428$). Using this table $(3)$, there are few ways more to choose exponents $n_k$ giving $B=0$ for the corresponding fonction $f(x)$, for example $z^{4n+2}+z^{4n+3}$ has at first sight  imaginary part equal to $0$ so four distinct pairs of these give a fonction $f(x)$ such that $f(z)$ has $B=0$ but the real part $A$ will be directly computable and distinct of eight.
Example.- We remark that $z^6+z^7+z^8=8$ so, using table $(3)$, we can show many examples of $f(x)=8$ .
The one with the lowest possible exponents is  $$f(x)=(x^6+x^7+x^8)+x^{10}+x^{14}+x^{18}+x^{22}+x^{26}$$  in which $f(1)=8=A$ but $B=-6560\ne0$.
Due to the presence of the factor $(-4)^n$ it is impossible that there are three or more other $z^{n_k}$ with imaginary part distinct of zero such that their sum is equal to eight. I claim that the only possible example is the one given.
I have finished my answer: there are not a fonction as the required $f(x)$.

Noting $\delta_i=1\text { or } 0$, we have for $f$ of $n$ degree
$$f_n(x)=x^n+\sum_{i=n-1}^{i=1}\delta_ix^i+\delta_0 $$ It follows that
$$f_n(x)-8=x^n+\sum_{i=n-1}^{i=1}\delta_ix^i-a \text { where } a=-8\text {  or } -7$$
Besides $$f_n(x)-8=(x^{n-3}+b_{n-4}x^{n-4}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0)(x^3+2x^2-2)$$ then $-2b_0=-8\text {  or } -7$ so discarded that $a=-7$ and $b_0=4$ (I assume that $g(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$).
We have successively $$(x^{n-3}+\cdots +b_1x+4)(x^3+2x^2-2)\implies -2b_1=\delta_1\implies b_1=0\\(x^{n-3}+\cdots +b_2x^2+4)(x^3+2x^2-2)\implies -2b_2+8=\delta_2\implies b_2=4$$ $$(x^{n-3}+\cdots +b_3x^3+4x^2+4)(x^3+2x^2-2)\implies -2b_3+4=\delta_3\implies b_3=2$$
$$(x^{n-3}+\cdots +b_4x^4+2x^3+4x^2+4)(x^3+2x^2-2)\implies -2b_4+8=\delta_4\implies b_4=4$$
$$(x^{n-3}+\cdots +b_5x^5+4x^4+2x^3+4x^2+4)(x^3+2x^2-2)\implies -2b_5+4+4=\delta_5$$ This implies $b_5=4$ and similarly we get
$-2b_6+8+2=\delta_6\implies b_6=5$ and so on...
The crucial fact is that always we have $b_m\gt1$ so never we get an unitary factor like the necessary $g(x)=x^{n-3}+b_{n-4}x^{n-4}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0$. This finish the proof.
Note:You, Calvin, asked about another proof and maybe you could consider that the proof of never we can have an unitary polynomial $g(x)$ requires more rigor. Do it if you want this final not hard step. I have do my best.

Good answer. How can you prove $b_m > 1$?

The divisor should be $x^3+x^2-2$, not $x^3 + 2 x^2 - 2$.

In addition to the above comments (showing that it never terminates, wrong divisor used), this is my proof of hunting down the coefficients of $a_i$ starting from $x^0, x^1, x^2$. So I don't quite consider it distinct, unless you have a different way to finish the argument, so please add this "final not hard step".

@Calvin Lin: In fact I have proved that it is not possible for $n=4,5$ and $n=6$ because necessarily $(b_4,b_5,b_6)=(4,4,5)$ and it is easy to see that successively never we have $b_m=1$. I am $86$ years-old and  often make slips of the pen (I confess that I feel lazy to read your answer and that's why I was confused about the trinomial). Now I edited changing a wrong $\delta_4$ by $\delta_5$ but, forgive me ,please, I won't edited anymore.

@WimC: Yes it was wrong reading. Forgive me, please, not to edit my answer. Basically it  could be the same proof and even easier with $x^3+x^2-2$ instead of $x^3+2x^2-2$. Regards.

@Maxime Jaccon: You always will have $-2b_i+n=\delta_i$. Look at parity  of $n$ and $n\gt2$ (induction works surely for that).
